# scala - it is possible to create "Int increment extension method" that can be invoked from any package?

Tags: scala

I wonder if i can create an implicit increment or "++" operator on "Int" type
that i can be invoked from any scope in my code.

(i.e from any package)

so for exampe:

```
var x = 4
x++
println(x) // will print 5
```

thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't. What's that wrong with `x += 1` that you really need your `++` back?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an implicit class at a high level (util package). I was able to achieve this using explicit type ascription:

```
object RichPrimitive {
  implicit class RichInt(var int: Int) {
    def ++ = int = int + 1
  }
}

import RichPrimitive.RichInt

var x: RichInt = 4 // if you don't do : RichInt, this does not work
x ++

println(x.int) // returns 5
```

Not entirely sure why the implicit did not take care of it (without it `println` for `x` returned a `4`).

Comment: This looks quite different from what kevinjoeiy asks for in all the key aspects (such as works in any scope, works  on the `Int` type).

Comment: Having the implicit class in a util location allows it to be imported into any location within a given package.
It works with the `Int` type as well - just need an explicit type ascription

Comment: We clearly understand @kevinjoeiy requirements quite differently so let him be the judge.

Answer (score 0):

No.

1. Implicit classes don't allow you to change a variable. Note that this is not the same as mutability vs immutability (i.e. changing a 1 to a 2 is changing a variable, not mutating the Int. To contrast, adding a value to a `collection.mutable.Map` is mutating the Map, not changing the variable that holds the map)
2. Even if they did allow you to change a variable, implicit classes always need to be imported if you want to use them outside the scope where you define them. You might define your `implicit class RichInt` in a package object for the main package in your code, but if you want to use it from any other package, you'll still need to import it.

That said, @Tanjin's answer is a fair approximation of what you want.